# "IF" excel formula has Parse error

Tags: excel, parsing, if-statement

I input a formula in excel, and it gave me an error, when I open the application. "Error parsing expression"

My formula is : `=IF(ISBLANK(C33);MAX(A18;MAX(A19;0));C33)`

or `=IF(ISBLANK(I13);MAX(A18;A19;0));I13)`

This formula works in other reports, which I have created.

Could anyone help me with this?

BTW, A18 and A19 are formulas, too.

Thank you!

Comment: Simply replace all the `;` with `,` which is the correct argument delimiter

Comment: @AlexK. Hi, thank you, I tried it just now. It seems with this version of excel, only ";" works.

Comment: @AlexK. not necessarily. That is a regional setting.

Comment: There is something about your environment you are not sharing.  How do you know the error is from that formula, which looks OK on the surface.  Are you running any queries which might be involved?